# How can I found a specific data in jpg image file by PHP

Tags: php

I have a very much of jpg images, these images are copy of contract. and i need PHP script that can check these images if it had a fingerprint and stamp and barcode and image of person. Thanks in advance.

Comment: fingerprint on digital images?

Comment: "image of person" - if you are searching for faces, Picasa recognize faces and groups them.

Comment: No way to do that with PHP. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://www.xarg.org/2008/07/face-detection-with-php/ for using face detection in PHP.

Comment: Upvoted! Not an answer to the question, but interesting to see face detection implemented in php.